# JPA garbage value in FK column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

When ever I add new child record I have a garbage value that starts appearing in FK column.Following are my classes and database values.
I am not sure whether I am putting any JPA or hibernate annotation wrong or is it a code issue.

Parent Class:

```
@Component
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private String name;

    private int parentRef;


    private BigDecimal price;


    private int prod_ID;


    private String prodType;


    private String remarks;


    private int supplier_ID;


    private String UOM;

    public Product() {
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Column(name = "ParentRef")
    public int getParentRef() {
        return this.parentRef;
    }
    @Column(name = "Price")
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Prod_ID")
    public int getProd_ID() {
        return this.prod_ID;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProdType")
    public String getProdType() {
        return this.prodType;
    }
    @Column(name = "Remarks")
    public String getRemarks() {
        return this.remarks;
    }
    @Column(name = "Supplier_ID")
    public int getSupplier_ID() {
        return this.supplier_ID;
    }
    @Column(name = "UOM")
    public String getUOM() {
        return this.UOM;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setParentRef(int parentRef) {
        this.parentRef = parentRef;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setProd_ID(int prod_ID) {
        this.prod_ID = prod_ID;
    }

    public void setProdType(String prodType) {
        this.prodType = prodType;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    public void setSupplier_ID(int supplier_ID) {
        this.supplier_ID = supplier_ID;
    }

    public void setUOM(String UOM) {
        this.UOM = UOM;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Name = "+ this.getName() +"\n ParentRef="+this.getParentRef() +"\n Prod ID="+this.getProd_ID() +"\n ProdType= "+getProdType() +"\n Remarks= "+getRemarks()+"\n Supplier_ID="+getSupplier_ID()+"\n UOM = "+getUOM()+"\nPrice ="+getPrice();

    }

}
```

Child Class:

```
@Entity(name="Productdetail")
public class ProductDetail implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable=true , name = "Color")
    private String Color;

    @Column(nullable=true , name = "Designno")
    private String DesignNo;

    @Column(nullable=true , name = "Imgpath")
    private String ImgPath;

    @Column(nullable=true , name = "IsScrap")
    private Integer IsScrap;


    private Product Prod_ID;


    @Id
    @TableGenerator(
            name="ProdDetailID", 
            table="ID_GEN", 
            pkColumnName="GEN_KEY", 
            valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", 
            pkColumnValue="ProdDetailID", 
            allocationSize=1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="ProdDetailID")
    @Column(name = "Proddetail_ID")
    private Integer ProdDetail_ID;

    @Column(nullable=true , name = "Remarks")
    private String Remarks;

    public ProductDetail() {

    }


    public ProductDetail(String remarks, String imgPath, String designNo, String color, Integer isScrap,
            Integer prodDetail_ID) {
        super();
        Remarks = remarks;
        ImgPath = imgPath;
        DesignNo = designNo;
        Color = color;
        IsScrap = isScrap;
        //Prod_ID = prod_ID;
        ProdDetail_ID = prodDetail_ID;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return Color;
    }

    public String getDesignNo() {
        return DesignNo;
    }

    public String getImgPath() {
        return ImgPath;
    }

    public Integer getIsScrap() {
        return IsScrap;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="Prod_ID" )
    public Product getProd_ID() {
        return Prod_ID;
    }

    public Integer getProdDetail_ID() {
        return ProdDetail_ID;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return Remarks;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        Color = color;
    }

    public void setDesignNo(String designNo) {
        DesignNo = designNo;
    }

    public void setImgPath(String imgPath) {
        ImgPath = imgPath;
    }

    public void setIsScrap(Integer isScrap) {
        IsScrap = isScrap;
    }

    public void setProd_ID(Product prod_ID) {
        Prod_ID = prod_ID;
    }

    public void setProdDetail_ID(Integer prodDetail_ID) {
        ProdDetail_ID = prodDetail_ID;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        Remarks = remarks;
    }


}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@PostMapping(value="/save")
    private void SaveData(@ModelAttribute ProductDetail productDetail ,@RequestParam("Product") int productID) {

        productDetail.setProd_ID( getProductList().get(productID) );
        System.out.println(productDetail.getProd_ID());
        prodDetailService.save(productDetail);


    }

     @GetMapping(value = "/NewOrder")
        public String NewProduct(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("product", new Product());
            model.addAttribute("productDetail", new ProductDetail());

            model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
            model.addAttribute("orderDetial", new OrderDetail());
            model.addAttribute("productList", getProductList());

            return "NewOrder";      // Returns page named mentioned
        }

    protected List<Product> getProductList() {
        productlist = new ArrayList<Product>();
        productlist = ProdService.findAll();;
        return productlist; 

    }
```

Database value of child table are :
Prod_ID is containing some unknown values.

```
 ProdDetail_ID Prod_ID    Color DesignNo  ImgPath IsScrap Remarks 
 ------------- ---------- ----- --------- ------- ------- ------- 
             3 **1946157361** Red   design    NULL       NULL NULL   
             4 **1946157361** Red   design    NULL       NULL NULL
```

Parent table is :

```
 Prod_ID Name       Price UOM   ProdType ParentRef Supplier_ID Remarks 
 ------- ---------- ----- ----- -------- --------- ----------- ------- 
       1 Lawn        NULL pcs   2 pcs            1           1 1      
       2 TestData    2500 Meter 3                0           1 Remarks
```

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: You annotate FIELDS or PROPERTIES, but NOT BOTH.

Comment: Also, respect the Java naming conventions. It's really not that hard.

Comment: So what should I do ?